# How to size CameraPreview without stretching the preview with Flutter camera plugin

Tags: flutter, camera

I am trying to size my camera preview to a specific size (for example width to 500 and height to 75). I am able to size it, but the preview becomes stretched, and also the output image is not sized as per the specified size.

Anyone has faced a similar issue or has any suggestions on how to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

```
              Container(
                height: Get.height * 0.1,
                width: Get.width * 0.8,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
                child: ClipRect(
                  child: OverflowBox(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                      child: Container(
                        width: Get.width * 0.8,
                        height: Get.width /
                            Get.find<CameraScannerController>()
                                .controller
                                .value
                                .value
                                .aspectRatio,
                        child: CameraPreview(
                            Get.find<CameraScannerController>()
                                .controller
                                .value),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can share a snippet of what you've already tried!

Comment: @StefanoAmorelli I have added the code snippet to the question.